# How to model this NoSQL data structure in Firestore (Review my first approach)

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, denormalization

I am a fairly new web developer and would need your help with a project I am currently working on. I have worked in the past on a very simple realtime database example and have little to none experience in firestore or NoSql in general.

I want to create a system which allows end-users to get an email once a week that contains a list of special offers from bars the end-user has subscribed to. The offers change each day of the week. Bar owners can fill out a form in a vue.js web application every week with their weekly special offers.

Every Monday morning a cron job has to look up which end user has subscribed to which bars and then aggregate the data and send it via email.

The question is how would you structure the data so that I can easily compose the email and send it via a cloud function?

My approach would be to have three main collections: RestaurantOwner, EndUser, SpecialOfferings

Please see the graphic for an example process:

[image]

BarOwner and EndUser are pretty straight forward. However, the difficult part is how to structure the SpecialOffers in order to be queried the right way.

My idea would be to structure it based on the calendar week and link it to the uid from the barOwner:

```
specialOffers: {
    2019_CW27: {
        barUID001: {
            mon: {
                title: 'Banana Daiquir',
                price: 4.99,
            },
            tue: {
                title: 'After Five',
                price: 2.99,
            },
            wed: {
                title: 'Cool Colada',
                price: 6.99
            },
            thu: {
                title: 'Crantini',
                price: 5.99
            },
            fri: {
                title: 'French Martini',
                price: 4.99
            }
        },
        barUID002: {
            mon: {
                title: 'Gin & Tonic',
                price: 8.99,
            },
            tue: {
                title: 'Cratini',
                price: 4.99,
            },
            wed: {
                title: 'French Martini',
                price: 4.99
            },
            thu: {
                title: 'After Five',
                price: 3.99
            },
            fri: {
                title: 'Cool Colada',
                price: 6.99
            }
        }
    },
    2019_CW28: { 
        barUID01: {~~~},
        barUID02: {~~~}
    }    
}
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that it creates a deeply nested object when you imagine that there are 52 calendar weeks, f.e 100 signed up bars à 5 special offers per week and I am not sure if I am able to query it the way I need to.

**Is this approach reasonable or what would you do differently?**

Thank you so much for your help! I highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the following scenarios:

1) The bar owners make modifications to their offers very often.

2) The bar owners should be the only ones allowed to modify each bar's offers.

If you have these two scenarios, I would recommend a sub-collections approach here.

**When to use sub-collections:**

1) When there are lot of fields in a document. Cloud Firestore has 20,000 field limit. (If the number of `Bars` can exceed more than 20,000 fields)

2) When updating the parent collection is a common operation. Firestore only lets you update the document at rate of 1 write/second. (If the `SpecialOffers` information  of each bar is modified very often. If two bar owners modify their offers, only 1 write is successful and the second write operation waits until the first is completed. This can delay the updation offers particularly at the end of a week when almost all the bars update the offers.)

3) When you want to limit the access to particular fields of a document. (If you want to restrict the access to a Bar's Offers to the `barOwner` alone. You can restrict the access to each document in the `Bars` sub-collection according to its owner using [Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions))

So I would recommend a sub-collection `Bars` under the main collection `SpecialOffers`. This way the design becomes scalable and you can add restaurants and super-markets as other similar sub-collections in the future without heavily altering your design.

Another advantage is that sub-collections are basically collections and they don't have a limit for number of documents it can hold. So even if the number of bars registered is above 20,000 which is the limit of number of fields for a fire-store document, your sub-collection wont be having a problem but your document will run out of fields to save the offers for a new bar.

Ultimately the choice depends on your use cases.

Hope this helps.